# Admin panel not accessible in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have deployed the wordpress blog on my site sqlhelps.com. The site is hosted on asp.netdiscount server. I cannot access the sqlhelps.com/wp-admin. The error is as follows :

```
Warning: require_once(E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs/wp-admin/includes/user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs\wp-admin\includes\admin.php on line 60 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs/wp-admin/includes/user.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs\wp-admin\includes\admin.php on line 60
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Either **user.php** is not available on your server or you are giving the **wrong** path as you can see error is :

```
No such file or directory in E:\web\.......
```

Answer (score 0):

In E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs\wp-admin\includes\admin.php on line 60, try changing

```
require_once(E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs/wp-admin/includes/user.php)
```

to

```
require_once(E:\web\sqlhelpscom\htdocs\wp-admin\includes\user.php)
```

so all the slashes are going the same way.

Jason

Comment: there is no such direct path there, ABSPATH is used to give the path..

Comment: Change the slashes in ABSPATH to \ rather than /?

Comment: i have tried doing so to.. but do i need to change it throughout the application? or at a specific page??

Comment: ABSPATH is defined in wp-config.php